# How to use Regex to convert initial letter of a string to upper case

Tags: regex, rubymine, case-conversion

Given a bunch of strings in an editor (e.g., Rubymine or IntelliJ) that look like this:

> list: ["required","TBD at time of entry", "respirator, gloves, coveralls, etc."]

How can I use the built-in Regex search and replace to convert the **initial** letter to **upper** case?

To this:

> list: ["Required","TBD at time of entry", "Respirator, gloves, coveralls, etc."]

NOTE WELL: The "TBD" should remain as "TBD" and not "Tbd"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may match any lowercase letter that is preceded with a `"`:

**Search**:   `(?<=")\p{Ll}`
**Replace**: `\U$0`

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/M7j86o/1/). Check ***Match Case*** to ensure matching only lower case letters.

**Details**

- `(?<=")` - a positive lookbehind that ensure that the preceding char is a `"`
- `\p{Ll}` - any Unicode lowercase letter.

Note that `\U` - uppercase conversion operator - does not require the trailing `\E` if you needn't restrict its scope and `$0` backreference refers to the whole match value, no need to wrap the whole pattern with a capturing group.

Answer (score 2):

(IntelliJ and RubyMine have Java regex rules in force I think.)

(For my future self) I used the following regex:

Search: `"(?)([a-z])`

Replace: `"\U$1\E`

BTW: Was not able to figure out why upper case letters were also selected. (shrug)

[image]

And it worked!